# Shortcuts not being triggered

Tags: qt, qt4

This is my class declaration:

```
class Browser : public QWidget {    
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Browser(QWidget *parent = 0);
        QStringList loadSettings(QString settings_file);
    private slots:
        void toggleFullscreen();               
    private:     
        void createActions();
        QAction *aToggleFullscreen;            
};
```

And relevand definitions:

```
void Browser::toggleFullscreen() {
    out << "fullscreen!" << endl;
}   
void Browser::createActions() {
    aToggleFullscreen = new QAction(this);
    aToggleFullscreen->setShortcut(tr("F11"));    
    connect(aToggleFullscreen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(toggleFullscreen()));    
}
```

I'm calling `createActions()` from `Browser::Browser`.

I have no runtime warning that slot doesn't exists, etc. But still nothing is triggered if I hit `F11`.

I tried also:

```
aToggleFullscreen->setShortcut(QString("F11"));
```

What is it wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually add your action to the Browser, so it never gets triggered. This should work:

```
void Browser::createActions() {
    aToggleFullscreen = new QAction(this);
    aToggleFullscreen->setShortcut(tr("F11"));    
    connect(aToggleFullscreen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(toggleFullscreen()));
    addAction(aToggleFullscreen);    
}
```